# $(p,q)$-5 webs from $M$-Theory

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, branes

The authors of the paper ["Webs of (p,q) 5-branes, Five Dimensional Field Theories and Grid Diagrams"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9710116) consider type $IIB$ superstring theory compactified on a circle $S^{1}$ and claim (in page 20) that there is a chain of string dualities between a given $(p,q)$-5 web wrapping the circle, and one $M5$-brane wrapping a $[(p,q)] \in H^{1}(T^{2},\mathbb{Z})$ cycle, with $M$-theory compactified on $T^{2}$.

**Question:** **Could anyone can show me the explicit brane configuration that maps one configuration into the other one?**

**Edit:**
@alexarvanitakis Has suggested me that I should try by constructing the T-dual of a pure $NS5/D5$ brane configuration. I think that's a great hint but I've the following problem with it: In order to obtain a pure $IIB$ $(p,q)$-5 web configuration, I must start with a $D4$-brane (the T-dual of an D5 brane) wrapping the base of a Taub-NUT (the T-dual of a $NS5$ brane). After T-dualizing the circle of the Taub-Nut, a $(p,q)$−5 web is obtained; unfortunately, I do not know how to lift Taub-NUT space to M-theory.

Comment: Try going to IIA first, then to IIB, obtaining pure NS5 and pure D5 to start with

Comment: Dear @alexarvanitakis. Thanks for the hint,  What troubles me is the following: In order to obtain a pure $IIB$ $(p,q)$-5 web configuration, I must start with a $D4$-brane (the $T$-dual of an $D5$ brane) wrapping the base of a Taub-NUT(the $T$-dual of a $NS$-5 brane). After $T$-dualizing the circle of the Taub-Nut, a $(p,q)-5$ web is obtained; unfortunately, **I do not know how to lift Taub-NUT space to $M$-theory**. If you know, I would appreciate if You could share your knowledge.

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head but I'm sure it's a '90s observation. It's probably in 1209.6056

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable comment and time. It's helpful, I'm sure the strategy you suggest is the correct one. Thanks!